# Azure disk performance

Tags: performance, raid, hard-drive, azure

I am running on-demand, research `D14` instance in Azure South Central US region, with a 4-disk RAID0. Recently the disk performance has become unusably slow, particularly the RAID performance, which is almost worse than the drives that make it. 
This behavior is new in the last few days -- it used be north of 150MB/s. 
There's no new load on the machine.

How can I improve performance?

---

#### HD Performance with `hdparm -t`:

```
$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/md127 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf

/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 110 MB in  3.05 seconds =  36.12 MB/sec

/dev/sdb:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1286 MB in  3.00 seconds = 428.44 MB/sec

/dev/md127:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  52 MB in  3.77 seconds =  13.80 MB/sec

/dev/sdc:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  46 MB in  3.42 seconds =  13.45 MB/sec

/dev/sdd:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  54 MB in  3.15 seconds =  17.14 MB/sec

/dev/sde:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  40 MB in  3.14 seconds =  12.75 MB/sec

/dev/sdf:
 Timing buffered disk reads:  62 MB in  3.05 seconds =  20.35 MB/sec
```

#### RAID0:

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md127

/dev/md127:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Oct  4 14:00:57 2014
     Raid Level : raid0
     Array Size : 1048573952 (1000.00 GiB 1073.74 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Oct  4 14:00:57 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : datacrunch:127  (local to host datacrunch)
           UUID : 2450cdf6:27e90d49:467e1esd:4c96b8f7
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       81        1      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       3       8       65        3      active sync   /dev/sde1
```

Comment: How do you know there is no new load on the machine - the machine is the host and the storage below, not your VM.

Comment: Fair point. I should have specified that I did not add new load into the system, hence it must-be/probably-is external. However, I am surprised that the RAID is so slow -- not faster at all than the HDs that make it. Is this normal / expected?

Comment: Depends. How do you know that the raid is not on the same backend? Just asking - from within a VM that is not a given.

Comment: How can I find out? That's the essence of my questions: How to improve the cr@p performance? :-)

Comment: You can not. The whole essence of a VM is the isolation. You need to control the physical level to know how the physical level is loaded.